# Does one run or stand for election?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does a person run or stand for election? I have a sentence that reads: "Now  is the time to start thinking of standing for election to a lodge office." I have been told that it should read: "...run for lodge office." Is that true?

Comment: Four answers to this question ended up being essentially the same. Normally such multiplication would be objectionable, but in this case it is understandable as the answers were posted within minutes of each other and were thus probably composed independently.

Answer (score 11):

In the US, *run for office* is much more common than either *run for election* or *stand for election*. Consider [this NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=run%20for%20office,%20run%20for%20election,%20stand%20for%20election&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3) (American English corpus):

[image]

Thus, if you are in the US, I'd agree with the correction you were suggested, especially since *run for [office]* can be and usually is used with the name of a specific office. Since your sentence talks about not just a generic election, but election to a *lodge office*, it seems a little redundant  to say *standing for election to a lodge office* when you could just say *running for a lodge office*.

**Addendum**: Though this wouldn't really fit in the example sentence you gave, if you want a stock phrase of similar meaning that uses the word *election*, Americans often say that a person *is up for election*. e.g. "Bush was up for election in 2000, and again in 2004."

Comment: People also replace *office* with the name of the office (e.g., *run for mayor*), which I personally find off-putting but which is much more common than *run for the office of mayor*.

Comment: Being up for election is about trying to get reelected, rather than a first attempt.

Answer (score 5):

One may *[stand for election](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/stand+for)* or *[run for election](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Run)*; either form is correct, although one might be more likely to say *stand for election* and *run for office*.

Running up the Google [N-grams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=run+for+election%2C+stand+for+election&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3):-

[image: stand for vs run for, all English]

suggests that *stand for* is more common than *run for*, although the difference is less marked when one selects the [American English](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=run+for+election%2Cstand+for+election&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3) option:-

[image: stand for vs run for, American English]

Comment: -1 Please include links along with the pictures.  I like to be able to try variations of ngrams searches without having to start from scratch typing in all the words.

Comment: Type ngrams in [] brackets, then the URL http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=run+for+election%2Cstand+for+election&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3 in () parentheses and then a phrase like "for *run for election,stand for election*".  On linux I use my [qenqote](http://pat7.com/qenqote) menu [qset-qenqote.xml](https://sourceforge.net/projects/qenqote/files/)  to do that.

Comment: @jwpat7: I don't think it is fair to "demand" that people include links to Ngrams. The picture is clear enough: no information or reference is withheld from viewers. If you want to test variations, you can easily go to Ngrams yourself and do so. Especially your (now retracted) down-vote seemed unnecessary.

Comment: @Cerberus - Please raise the question on Meta rather than here, & provide link to it

Comment: why are your results so different than alcas answer?

Comment: @JeffAtwood, it looks like they are the same (for the American corpus) except alcas has added _run for office_ to his diagram, which makes the other two rather small by comparison. The bumps in _stand for election_ around 1940 and 1960 are visible, as is the smaller peak for _run for election_ just before 1980.

Comment: @jwpat7: Wouldn't you rather do it? You raised the issue.

Comment: @Cerberus Please see meta [question 2325](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2325/should-one-downvote-a-question-because-of-missing-source-links).

Answer (score 2):

In the UK, a parliamentary candidate *stands* for election. We don't have a presidency for candidates to *run* for.

Comment: Helpfully, we stand for election so that we might sit in Parliament.

Answer (score 2):

Here what the writer Emmet Fox (born in Ireland, raised in England, lived in the USA), wrote in 1953 on the difference between "stand" and "run":

> Take politics, for example.  Many people have a “slight” tendency to excessive criticism of the other side!  Have you noticed it—especially around election time?  Now that is a serious matter because if it is not checked, democracy may become impossible.  In democratic countries, if a candidate is going to be vilified and accused of every crime under the sun, **if a man stands, or runs—in England you stand for Parliament but in America you run for Congress (difference in tempo, you know)**—if, as soon as a man runs for governor, or mayor, or senator, or president, if he is going to be accused of every foul thing, what will happen?  Decent, sensitive men will not run for public office.  Only the toughest people will do it.  If the men who are really qualified in every way, with a high sense of honor, are going to be vilified like this, they will not run for office.  So it is very important not to attack people in politics in that unfair way.  I do not mean that they should not be criticized.  You can say that Jones’s policy is bad, but not that Jones is a crook or that he beats his wife, when you have seen Mrs. Jones and know quite well that it is probably the other way around!

Excerpted from: The Ten Commandments: The Master Key to Life, Harper and Row, 1953

Answer (score 1):

"Stands for election" seems to be primarily a UK phrase, as I've never heard of it before in the states. Here, you usually say someone is "running for office."

Comment: What does a candidate for Congress do? Is membership of Congress an 'office'?

Comment: @BarrieEngland: Then you usually say that they're "running for congress."

Comment: In the U.S. a Presidential candidate will have a "running mate" Vice-Presidential candidate, reinforcing the association.

Comment: @user653: Plus, they call it the "presidential race."

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between the two, technically. If I'm not mistaken, Andrew Jackson was the first politician to 'run' for an office. 'Standing' meant that one was nominated by others and chose to be considered by a vote. 'Running' did not happen for a bit; one ran for office if they nominated themselves.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This might apply to some extent (maybe it explains the origin of "run for office") but there's a geographical difference between the US and UK which isn't based on this distinction. Regardless, it should be possible to use the OED or similar historical dictionary to find if the use of the terms matches this hypothesis.

Comment: While this answer would profit from some elaboration, it is an important addition to the answers posted earlier (although the one by Paul may be read as hinting at the same idea) in that it tries to explore an arguable difference between the two terms that goes beyond one being more common in BrEn and the other in AmEn. Even in American English, one would be unlikely to say that somebody is running for some office if that person only reluctantly agreed to be a candidate for it and is not putting much effort into campaigning; *run* implies a certain amount of active self-promotion.